# ggplot2: mixing simple and grouped bars in a single bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `data.frame` :

```
df <- structure(list(sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), replicate = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    treatment = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("V0", 
    "V2", "V4", "V6"), class = "factor"), mean = c(72.5, 66.4, 
    60.3, 56.3, 90.7, 86.9, 68.8, 64.6, 73.3, 69.8, 62.3, 68.7, 
    77.1, 73.6, 65.9, 65.3, 75.7, 73.8, 65.9, 66.8), sd = c(5.4, 
    6.1, 3.5, 4.7, 1.2, 4.9, 8.4, 6.1, 7.3, 3.5, 5.9, 2.2, 3.2, 
    3, 3.1, 4.2, 4.2, 2.4, 2.2, 2.6)), .Names = c("sample", "replicate", 
"treatment", "mean", "sd"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

For some samples I have replicates while for others I don't :

```
> head(df, 15)
   sample replicate treatment mean  sd
1       A         1        V0 72.5 5.4
2       A         1        V2 66.4 6.1
3       A         1        V4 60.3 3.5
4       A         1        V6 56.3 4.7
5       B         1        V0 90.7 1.2
6       B         1        V2 86.9 4.9
7       B         1        V4 68.8 8.4
8       B         1        V6 64.6 6.1
9       C         1        V0 73.3 7.3
10      C         1        V2 69.8 3.5
11      C         1        V4 62.3 5.9
12      C         1        V6 68.7 2.2
13      C         2        V0 77.1 3.2
14      C         2        V2 73.6 3.0
15      C         2        V4 65.9 3.1
```

I would like to plot means in a faceted bar plot for each `sample` value. I would like to get grouped bars when replicates > 1. Is it possible with ggplot2 ?

What I get so far :

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=treatment, y=mean, fill=sample)) 
g <- g + geom_bar(position="dodge")
g <- g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+sd, ymin=mean-sd), position="dodge")
g <- g +  facet_grid(. ~ sample)

g
```

[image: bar plot]

**EDIT**

Following the suggestion of @Tyler Rinker, I get :

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=treatment, y=mean, fill=replicate))
g <- g + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
g <- g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+sd, ymin=mean-sd), position="dodge", width=0.25)
g <- g +  facet_grid(. ~ sample)
```

[image: test2]

However, I would like to get the bars for the 'C' sample replicates displayed side-by-side.

**EDIT2** Very close to ...

Simply by adding `group` = `replicate` :

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=treatment, y=mean, group=replicate, fill=replicate))
g <- g + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
g <- g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+sd, ymin=mean-sd), position="dodge", width=0.25)
g <- g +  facet_grid(. ~ sample)
```

[image: test3]

However there is a remaining problem with the position of the error bars. I guess I have to play with dodge ? But I don't know how ...

**EDIT3** Eventually... thanks to @joran

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)
```

I checked that other values than 0.9 did not lead to a correct positioning of the error bars

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=treatment, y=mean, group=replicate, fill=replicate))
g <- g + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") 
g <- g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+sd, ymin=mean-sd), position=dodge, width=0.25, color="black")
g <- g +  facet_grid(. ~ sample)
```

[image: test4]

Comment: What do you mean by grouped bars?

Comment: I haven't read carefully but I think you want `geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +`  Not sure about the rest of what you want.

Comment: @Maiasaura For one x-value, I get several bars. In my example, I expect to have 3 bars for each x-value for the 'C' sample.

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanks for your suggestion. That brings me one step further but I get the bars superposed and not presented side-by-side as expected...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this and experiment a bit:

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width = 0.9)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=treatment, y=mean, group=replicate, fill=replicate))
g <- g + geom_bar(position=dodge, stat="identity")
g <- g + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=mean+sd, ymin=mean-sd), position = dodge,width = 0.25)
g <- g +  facet_grid(. ~ sample)
g
```

I think the different dodging in each panel was confusing the width setting. I'd have to read up a bit on the details of dodging (and there are several people around these parts who may be able to weigh in more easily than myself...) but I *think* that when you set the dodging "locally" in each geom, ggplot is deciding things about widths based upon information in each layer separately. So the trick here seemed to be to ensure a "global" dodge setting.

Comment: Thanks ! It works... I don't really understand why we have to set this 'width' value to 0.9 but it does the job !

Comment: @ptocquin It's not the specific width; experiment a bit changing it. As I noted in my edit, I think the key part is ensuring that ggplot is using the same width for dodging in each layer, rather than choosing a width "by default" for each layer.